# browse images without Gallery View android

Tags: android

i'm trying to browse images like in the Gallery View but with an image view. While the user touches and moves the finger to the left a new picture is shown with some nice animation transition. Can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) widget. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513578/android-viewflipper-gesture-detector) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is special [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) widget for such case. [Here is good example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html) from android developers on how to use it.